# Forcing first initials in bibliography, but adjust "F." to "Fdez." for just one reference?

Tags: biblatex

I am in a situation where I want to use first initials with the Biblatex package. However, in one instance, I want "Fernandez" to be instead shortened to "Fdez.".

I know I could construct the reference manually using only the "note" field, but perhaps there is a simpler way I am not aware of?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, giveninits=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
  @article{fernandez2016,
    author = {Fernandez Smith},
    title     = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year      =  {2016},
    volume = {1},
    number = {1},
    pages   = {1--2}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
It was first stated by \textcite{fernandez2016} that \ldots

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you give a short MWE of what you are doing currently? Do you use the `giveninits` option to get first initials?

Comment: @moewe It has been done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there appears to be just one entry that's in need of this special abbreviation form, you could try the "brute force" approach, viz., replace

```
author = {Fernandez Smith},
```

with

```
author = {{\relax Fdez} Smith},
```

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
  @article{fernandez2016,
    author    = {{\relax Fdez} Smith},
    title     = {Title},
    journal   = {Journal},
    year      = {2016},
    volume    = {1},
    number    = {1},
    pages     = {1--2}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```